# Value not populating in output

Tags: json, mapping, transformation, jolt

Using JOLT I am trying to multiply value of PRICE_PO and QTY_PO value and I am expecting the answer in **itemTotalAmount** field but **itemTotalAmount** is not populating in the output file.

**Input JSON**

```json
{
  "PURCHASE_ORDER_DISPATCH": {
    "MsgData": {
      "Transaction": {
        "PO_POD_HDR_EVW1": {
          "PO_POD_LN_EVW1": {
            "PO_POD_SHP_EVW1": {
              "PRICE_PO": 14.99,
              "QTY_PO": 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**JOLT Spec**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "PURCHASE_ORDER_DISPATCH": {
        "MsgData": {
          "Transaction": {
            "PO_POD_HDR_EVW1": {
              "PO_POD_LN_EVW1": {
                "PO_POD_SHP_EVW1": {
                  "PRICE_PO": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.marketPrice",
                  "QTY_PO": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.itemQuantity",
                  "e($.PRICE_PO * $.QTY_PO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.itemTotalAmount"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Expected output with **itemTotalAmount**-**

```
{
 "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails": {
   "integrationEntities": {
     "integrationEntity": {
       "integrationEntityDetails": {
         "poDetails": {
           "items": {
             "item": {
               "marketPrice": 14.99,
               "itemQuantity": 1,
               "itemTotalAmount":14.99
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Your input is xml. I think you have mistake in your question!

Comment: @MohammadReza I have updated my code with JSON.

Comment: Current output.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I have updated the code with expected output. Please refresh the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add **modify** and **remove** transformations successively to the current spec such as

```json
[
  ...,
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "*": {
                    "product": "=divide(1,@(1,itemQuantity))",
                    "itemTotalAmount": "=divide(@(1,marketPrice),@(1,product))"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "*": {
                    "product": ""
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

there is no **`multiply`** function but **`divide`** (or **`divideAndRound`**) which is used within the **modify** transformation, and the auxiliary attribute(**`product`**) is deleted by **remove** spec

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]